# EAS completed APK build not working on some Androids, but Expo build works on all

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm building a react native app using Expo's managed app service.

The app has been working great and bug-free on all android phones using the Expo Build:android apk.
Yesterday I upgraded to the 45 expo SDK and have built the app using the EAS build command.
Now, the app works on all iOS devices, but some android now crash on start-up, some work as always.

The app shows the logged-in stack for a brief moment, before showing the splash screen.

What could be the cause?

Package Json:

```
  "name": "tut3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~13.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~11.2.3",
    "expo-camera": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-device": "~4.2.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-firebase-analytics": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.3.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-location": "~14.2.2",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~11.2.0",
    "expo-network": "~4.2.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.15.2",
    "firebase": "^9.6.11",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "0.30.1",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "shorthash": "^0.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

EAS.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.52.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

The command I'm running:

`eas build --profile production --platform android`

Comment: I had your same problem, did you add firebase to your project? If you did not, please [read my answer in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74212344/8139569).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create index.js and import "./App" like below

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import App from './App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

and delete the entire line

> "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",

from package.json.

Check reference [custom--main--entry-point-in](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#custom--main--entry-point-in)